# typescript: Use enum value as key in interface containing spaces

Tags: typescript

I have an enum and I want to add its *values* to an interface, but getting this error:

> A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1169)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglsANgEwM5QN4CgpQOQgCGEweUAvPgGYIoCMeANDvoQOakW541LIBMTFngDGYVABcA9tF4oylHrWQBmIQF8sWOCAnAATlUIjgUAAoHUUkJhZxkALiiT9OtgG4WAbXh9UX0XFpWWU8AF0wgH4nFzdPdSA

How could I use enum values as interface properties without having to create a second enum with the reverse key/values?

```
enum Fields {
  'name' = 'field1',
  'age' =  'field2',
  'custom field' = 'field3',
}

interface Person {
  id: string;
  [Fields['custom field']]?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want with an intermediate type, as follows:

```
enum Fields {
  'name' = 'field1',
  'age' =  'field2',
  'custom field' = 'field3',
}

type FieldsObject = {
    [K in Fields]? : string
}

interface Person extends FieldsObject {
  id: string;
}

const p: Person = {
  id: "abc",
  field1: "",
  field3: "",
}
```

[TypeScript Playground showing this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglsANgEwM5QN4CgpQOQgCGEweUAvPgGYIoCMeANDvoQOakW541LIBMTFngDGYVABcA9tF4oylHrWQBmIQF8sWCQE8ADsFjLUAeQBGAK2AiJXbLlwBtANJQ4II31QBdAPxQALihJACd3NixNLHcJYBCqQhFDAAU41CkPYAAPWJA0TxRTS2tbezdkINDwgG5IrREMySg9INSQ9I9KMrgKqAAiQjMRPuZcOWQ6IL6RlnGVKZn1IA)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it's ugly: basically, use a mapped type to define that property, and then intersect with a regular object type to define the rest of the properties. I used `Simplify` to make the result more readable.

```
type Simplify<T> = T extends unknown ? {[K in keyof T]: T[K]} : never

type Person = Simplify<{
  id: string;
} & {
  [K in typeof Fields['custom field']]?: string
}>
```

Hovering over `Person` in the Typescript Playground shows the result is equivalent to:

```
type Person = {
    id: string;
    field3?: string | undefined;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglsANgEwM5QN4CgpQOQgCGEweUAvPgGYIoCMeANDvoQOakW541LIBMTFngDGYVABcA9tF4oylHrWQBmIQF8sWCQE8ADsCgBlOBD2I4VHQB4AKgD4utqMAAeE0GihgQAaxBSAO4gUAD8mADaANJQcCG+wDpSVFC2ALoAXKnRaepQWSDAAG7AAE5augZQAAplqFIhlCZmFlbW2LhwyFmSpXFsANxYeQBkmCzRsSGVwMmwyqgRouLSssp4aWmhPRJ9IGzD9lhAA)